# extrema and range of a multivariable function (constrained)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{3+x^2+z^2}$

Constrained on : $D=\{x^2+z^2\le 3+y^2\}$

**Function not-constrained**:

$$\displaystyle
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
f_x=\frac{2x}{(3+x^2+z^2)^2}=0\\
f_y=0\\
f_z=\frac{2z}{(3+x^2+z^2)^2}=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

From here I can say that we have critical points at $(0,y,0)$. It seems also that we have a maximum  at $(0,0,0)=\frac{1}{3}$

**Function constrained**:

Using Lagrange multiplier method :
$$\displaystyle
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{2x}{(3+x^2+z^2)^2}=2x\lambda\\
0=-2y\lambda\\
\frac{2z}{(3+x^2+z^2)^2}=2z\lambda\\
x^2-y^2+z^2-3=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

From here I Found these points : $(0,0,\pm \sqrt{3}),(\pm\sqrt{3},0,0)$

The range (Image) of this function constrained should be : $Im(f)=[0,\frac{1}{6}]$

**Questions** :

Did I do right? Is that everything I can say about Its extremes?

Are $(0,y,0)$ points part of the answer (Can I say that the critical points are $(0,0,0)$,$(0,y,0)$)?

Comment: Under the constraint $Im(f)$ is $(0,\frac 1 3]$.

Comment: It seem $\frac{1}{3}$ is in outer space.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I plugged $(0,0,\pm \sqrt{3})$ into the function, which gives me $\frac{1}{6}$. Why should I stick with $\frac{1}{3}$ ? $(0,0,0)$ does not satify the constrain $x^2-y^2+z^2=3$